# Can I get a trained tesseract 5 (python) model for a specific font?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm new to tesseract and I've noticed that the accuracy isn't as high as I want it to be, so is there a way I could get a trained model for a certain font (Calibri to be specific), if it isn't possible then how can I do it myself?

Comment: do not use version-specific tags unless the _problem_ is specific to the version.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73006268/how-is-googles-ocr-this-good